# Break shutdown operation after perform shutdown windows 7

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

After clicking shutdown button of windows 7 start menu, i need to stop shutting down operation immediately. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to hit windows key and then type shutdown -a

Answer (score 0):

Lock the screen with <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. If you're fast enough it will interupt the shutdown.